# How to bind to one input box in ngFor

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

can someone please help me with some code, I have a simple `ngfor` table with an input that I bind the value the problem is since the input is being generated by the `ngFor` when I type in any of the input fields the same value get populated in all the fields. How can I stop this from happening I just want to type in a single field.

here is my code so far

```js
takePictureFromCamera(ven) {
  let options: CameraOptions = {
    quality: 15,
    destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
    encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
    mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
    sourceType: 1,
    cameraDirection: this.camera.Direction.BACK
  }

  this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {
    console.log('imageData: ', imageData);
    this.imageData = normalizeURL(imageData);
    console.log('normaliza imageData: ', this.imageData);

    var venName = ven.vendor;
    //
    var tok = localStorage['token'];
    // const params = new FormData();
    // params.append('token', tok);
    // params.append('vendor', venName);
    // params.append('total', '599');
    // params.append('slip', this.imageData );


    const fileTransfer: FileTransferObject = this.transfer.create();
    var total = parseFloat(this.inputVen);

    let options1: FileUploadOptions = {
      fileKey: 'slip',
      fileName: 'name.jpeg',
      chunkedMode: false,
      mimeType: "image/jpeg",
      headers: { 'token': tok, 'vendor': venName, 'total': total }
    };

    // let alert = this.alerCtrl.create({
    //     title: venName + total,
    // });
    // alert.present();

    fileTransfer.upload(this.imageData, 'http://192.168.0.7:8080/static/images/ionicfile.jpg', options1)
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data) + " Uploaded Successfully");
        // this.imageFileName = "http://192.168.0.7:8080/static/images/ionicfile.jpg"

        console.log(data);

        let alert = this.alerCtrl.create({
          title: JSON.stringify(data),
        });
        alert.present();

        this.inputVen = '';

      }, (err) => {
        console.log(err);

        let alert = this.alerCtrl.create({
          title: JSON.stringify(err),
        });
        alert.present();

      });
  }, (err) => {
    console.log('error: ', JSON.stringify(err));
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.11/angular.min.js"></script>
<table>
   <tr >
      <th>Vendor Name</th>
      <th>Total</th>
      <th>Slip</th>
   </tr>
   <tr *ngFor="let ven of VendorsS">
      <td> {{ven.vendor}}
      </td>
      <td ><input type="type" placeholder="Total" [(ngModel)]="inputVen" size="6px"/></td>
      <td>
         <button (click)="takePictureFromCamera(ven)">
            <ion-icon ios="ios-camera" md="md-camera"></ion-icon>
         </button>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are binding each input within the `*ngFor` to the same value in the model, `inputVen`.  It isn't entirely clear from the example what you are trying to do, but I assume you are trying to update the `total` property of the vendor.

Try binding to `ven.total` (or whatever the appropriate property of ven is that you want to update) instead of `inputVen`.

```
<tr *ngFor="let ven of VendorsS">
  <td> {{ven.vendor}}
  </td>
  <td ><input type="type" placeholder="Total" [(ngModel)]="ven.total" size="6px"/></td>
  <td>
     <button (click)="takePictureFromCamera(ven)">
        <ion-icon ios="ios-camera" md="md-camera"></ion-icon>
     </button>
  </td>
```

Then in your script file, instead of referencing `inputVen` use `ven.total`;

```
var total = parseFloat(ven.total);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do the following:

- Transform your inputVen in an array of values;
- Change your *ngFor to the following:

```
   <tr *ngFor="let ven of VendorsS; let i = index">
      <td> {{ven.vendor}}
      </td>
      <td ><input type="type" placeholder="Total" [(ngModel)]="inputVen[i]" size="6px"/></td>
      <td>
         <button (click)="takePictureFromCamera(ven)">
            <ion-icon ios="ios-camera" md="md-camera"></ion-icon>
         </button>
      </td>
   </tr>
```

Note that you can get the index on the for with "let i = index". That way you can do multiple bindings on the TypeScript array.
You can get more information about ngFor here: 
https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-ng-for-syntax
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the template to use the index from the ngFor and then in thr NgModel bind an array (using the index) and change the component to create inputVen as an array and set its length

```
//template
<tr *ngFor="let ven of VendorsS; let i = index">
    <td> {{ven.vendor}}
    </td>
    <td ><input type="type" placeholder="Total" [(ngModel)]="inputVen[i]" size="6px"/></td>
    <td>
        <button (click)="takePictureFromCamera(ven)">
        <ion-icon ios="ios-camera" md="md-camera"></ion-icon>
        </button>
    </td>
</tr>

//component
inputVen = []
...
this.inputVen = Array(this.VendorsS.length)
```